# c++ error 2679: binary'>>' : no operator found

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following error message while building my program:

> errorC2657: binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right hand
>   operand of type'const char[2]'(or there is no acceptable conversion)

Here is the source code of my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int number1;
int number2;
int intSum;
int intdiff;
int intprod;
int intaver;
cout << "Enter the 1st and 2nd ODD integers (separate them by a space):     ";
cin >> number1 >>" " >> number2;
intSum = abs(number1 + number2);
intdiff = abs(number1 - number2);
intprod = abs(number1 * number2);
intaver = abs((number1 + number2) / 2);
if ( number1%2 != 0)
    cout << "You must enter ODD integers! See you next time." <<endl;
else if ( number2%2 != 0)

    cout << "You must enter ODD integers! See you next time." <<endl;
else
{
    cout << "The sum of the integers is"<<intSum<<endl;
    cout << "The difference of the integers is"<<intdiff<<endl;
    cout << "The product of the integers is"<<intprod<<endl;
    cout << "The average of the integers is"<<intaver<<endl;   
    if (number1 > number2)
        cout << "The first one "<< number1 <<" is bigger." <<endl;
    else if (number2 > number1)
        cout << "The second one "<< number2 <<" is bigger." <<endl;
    else
        cout <<"Both numbers are the same."<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me fixing the problem. I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
cin >> number1 >> " " >> number2;
```

tries to ***write*** your input into `number1`, then a string literal (the `const char[2]`), then `number2`. That's not what you want, especially since the streams are smart enough to skip white space on their own:

```
cin >> number1 >> number2;
```

You can see this with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int i1, i2;
  std::cout << "Please enter two integers: ";
  std::cin >> i1 >> i2;
  std::cout << "You entered " << i1 << " and " << i2 << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

which, when run, works thus:

```
Please enter two integers:     4     77
You entered 4 and 77
```

Comment: Props for clarifying the `const char[2]`

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> number1 >>" " >> number2;`

needs to change to

```
cout << endl << "Enter first number : ";
cin >> number1;
cout << endl << "Enter second number : ";
cin >> number1;
```

The `>>` is an operator defined for `cin` as receiver, and the use of `const char[2]` type operand is illegal. The `" "` is the `const char[2]`, as paxDiablo explains. But yeah, do as PaxDiablo says, his way is better.

Comment: FirstJens, in the full expression `cin >> n1 >> n2`, the result of the subexpression `cin >> n1` is `cin`, so you *can* combine two inputs on one line. The only problem here is the use of `" "` attempting to skip a space. Not that it matters now, since you've changed your answer to be more correct. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
cin >> number1 >>" " >> number2;
```

Split it in two operations:

```
cin >> number1;
cin >> number2;
```

or

```
cin >> number1 >> number2;
```

`operator>>` of `cin` reads till the new line or a space. So it will take care of inputs separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` cannot accept string literals (`" "`). You need to separate the two inputs.

```
cin >> number1;
cin >> number2;
```

You can also obtain a string and parse it yourself.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>

std::string str;
cin >> str;
std::vector<std::string> strs;
boost::split(strs, "str", boost::is_any_of(" "));

int number1 = atoi(strs[0]);
int number2 = atoi(strs[1]);
```